# unsatisfied link: SolarisParallel using rxtx to replace java comm api in Windows XP

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

i'm trying to use the rxtx 2.0 jars and dll to use the java comm api in windows xp, i copied the RXTXcomm.jar to jre\ext and rxtxSerial.dll and rxtxParallel.dll to jre\bin

When I run the program I got the following error:

Error loading SolarisSerial: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SolarisSerialParallel in java.library.path
Caught java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.comm.SolarisDriver.readRegistrySerial(Ljava/util/Vector;Ljava/lang/String;)I while loading driver com.sun.comm.SolarisDriver

why is it trying to load the solaris driver??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows, I suggest using "Windows Java Serial Com Port Driver" rather than rxtx.
You can download it from http://www.engidea.com/blog/informatica/winjcom/winjcom.html
I've found it much easier to install and use and much more bug-free.
I was unable to use RXTX with USB serial devices because RXTX would crash when the USB port was unplugged.  winjcom solved these problems for me, and more.
-Stosh

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have an improperly configured properties file.

Locate Javax.comm.properties and search for this:

Driver=com.sun.commSolarisDriver

If you find it, comment it out and place it with:

Driver=gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver

This is [based on RXTXComm's install-japanese.html file, as translated by Google](http://tinyurl.com/bw8yog)